# Compile `.hex` files on Linux

Tags: linux

I build `.hex` files for Arduino. How can I do this in Linux? I use the Linux distro  Mint 17.2.

I need a program to make [`.hex` files] (in Linux).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: With the Arduino IDE of course.

Comment: What are you asking for? How to build `.hex` files on Linux? Or how to upload `.hex` files on Linux? Please clarify your question, because as it stands it is rather unclear and is likely to be closed.

Comment: @Majenko - I may be wrong, but looking at your edit, I would have said (as a non-native Brazilian Portugese speaker) that `Necessito de um programa para fazer.` should be translated as `I need a program to make [.hex files]`, rather than `I need to make a program`.This _may_ be the reason why the question seems a little unclear... :-)

Comment: @Greenonline Don't complain to me - complain to Google Translate ;)

Comment: @Majenko - ah, ok :-) Anyways, I've changed the meaning of the question, and it all makes a bit more sense now. I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Arduino IDE for Linux from [the Arduino site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).

As mentioned in [Where are the hex files compiled by Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607834/where-are-the-hex-files-compiled-by-arduino), in the Arduino program: go to **Arduino -> Preferences** and then select **Show verbose output during -> compilation**.

> Finally, when you are compiling, the program will show you lots of
>   data. At the last lines, you will find the path to the .hex file
>   (Every time the path changes!).

If you want to upload this `.hex` file to your **ATmega328P** (the micro controller inside Arduino Uno), `avrdude` can do that for you.

Here, are few useful links:

1. [Setup Avrdude on Linux](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-unix.html)
2. [Programming your chip](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/programming.html)
3. [Choosing a Programmer](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/programmers.html)
4. [Uploading your .hex file](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html)

Comment: ok. But it not is my problem.
I have an .hex file and I need compiler this file to the arduino.

Comment: Upload? Compile seems strange. Please elaborate.

Comment: from what i understand of your question is that you have a **.hex** file and you want to upload it to your Arduino Board. Well, First you need to know which microcontroller is being used in your Arduino Board you can use AVRDUDE, [as shown in this tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-unix.html), you can upload that **.hex** file to your micro controller. (Arduino UNO have a ATMega328P)

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer and the link only shows how to install avrdude, but not how to use it to upload a `.hex` file.

Comment: Unfortunately, you did paid attention while visiting the given link. There was menu in which different section were listed. Anyways, I have edited my answer.

Comment: No problem... It turns out that you were correct anyway, as the true meaning of the question had got lost in translation. I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

How are you creating your `.hex` files? Where are they coming from? Are you cross compiling the `.hex` files on some other machine and then transferring them to the Linux box? What is your Arduino connected to, the Linux box, or some other machine? Why are you even bothering with the .hex files? Your question is a little unclear. As Mikael states in [his comment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/compile-hex-files-on-linux#comment-44093), you do not need to *compile* the `.hex` files, they are already compiled, you merely need to *upload* them, which the Arduino IDE would do for you anyway...

As ARK points out in [his answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/compile-hex-files-on-linux#answer-23213), you may find the answers to the question [Where are the hex files compiled by Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607834/where-are-the-hex-files-compiled-by-arduino) useful, although it seems like you know where they are but you don't know how to upload them.

Why can you not just use the Arduino IDE, to write your sketch, and then allow it to *automatically* compile the sketch and upload the `.hex` file for you? That way you do not need to manually play with the `.hex` file. Maybe I am missing something.

Is the Arduino IDE bombing out and not uploading the sketch on to the Arduino board?

---

However, if you are merely asking, how can I upload a `.hex` file to an Arduino, in Linux without using the Arduino IDE, then you would use `avrdude`. Taking the answer from [How do I upload a hex file firmware to a target board without using the arduino IDE?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67121/how-do-i-upload-a-hex-file-firmware-to-a-target-board-without-using-the-arduino)

```
avrdude -C/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/build8135728863211847829.tmp/sketch_may21b.cpp.hex:i
```

or alternatively, taking the answer from [Uploading Arduino hex file using avrdude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780125/uploading-arduino-hex-file-using-avrdude)

```
avrdude -U flash:w:[put-hex-file-path-here]:i -C avrdude.conf -v -p atmega328 -b 115200 -c stk500v2 -P [put-device-path-here]
```